# How can I make a field optional?

Tags: plsql, jasper-reports

I use Oracle stored procedure in my jrxml report. It returns cursor as a result. I wish to be able to return different column sets, so some columns in cursor may appear or disappear.

However when column which I've described as a field

```
<field name="MY_COLUMN" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

doesn't exist in cursor it throws an error like this:

```
error while rendering
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unknown column name MY_COLUMN in result set
```

Is there any way to declare field in JRXML as optional? When the column doesn't exist in the result set.

Comment: @AlexK I've read all the questions above, none of them looks like my problem. So in a few words: I have cursor from stored procedures, but its column set may be suddenly changed by some other developers. And I wish that my report will not crush completely if cursor lose some unimportant column. So I'm looking for smth like optional attribute for report field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIK: There is no setting/attributes that you can set on your field declaration.

Your options are:

1. Always return the column name even if not available using [sql
   alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)) for example:

   ```
   SELECT column1, null as MY_COLUMN from myTable.
   ```
2. Create your own
   [`JRDatasource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html)
   which can be all from loading data into beans and passing a
   [`JRBeanCollectionDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html)
   to creating your own [`JRQueryExecuter`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRQueryExecuter.html) and register it to the factory.

Comment: Petter, I think that the first option doesn't suit because some stored procedures are shared between several subsystems and may be changed by other developers. But I wish to have report which will not crush completely if it doesn't find some unimportant column.

Comment: Then create an own datasource, load the data into beans and pass them to the report

Comment: The second one: to use java bean is Ok, but I lose all the benefits of shared stored procedure developed by some other guys and will always need to support the report myself modifying the bean on java-server.

Comment: Why is the bean modified? That you would only need to do if you need to modify the report e.g. a new field.

Comment: @Peter yes, as i mentioned, the solution is ok, and I can accept it, I just wanted to allow designers working in GUI of JasperStudio and DB developers to interact without my support.

Comment: It's not impossible to develop your own JRQueryExecutor hence do what you want just some more work

Comment: @Peter thank you, may be I'll try to do it, I'm just a bit surprised that such a simple problem has such nontrivial solution